# GWT Expand/Collapse boxes?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Im looking to create something like the image( https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2h1813c13v12y0/samp.jpg ) using GWT-UiBinder method. I cannot use a tree becoz i need the collapsed view to have - Title, a single field value , icons that that are like status symbols. The expanded view than contains the Title and icon like the collapsed but the value + additional values are displayed in detail.

please let me know your ideas! Examples would be great!! 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the [`DisclosurePanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DisclosurePanel.html)? (with a custom [header widget](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DisclosurePanel.html#setHeader%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget%29))

Comment: Ive looked at Disclosure planel but it allows only 1 title i need to add a field value and icons.

Comment: Hence the _custom header widget_.

Comment: Can you give me an example of customizing the DisclosurePanel's Header to have title,field value and icon?? thanx..

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a use case for [DeckLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DeckLayoutPanel.html).

You should then embed any widget Image/Input/CellTable/DataGrid in each container per "Deck".

You might have some good example here - http://www.slideshare.net/martyhall/gwt-tutorial-laying-out-windows-with-panels-part-ii-composite-panels#btnNext

**Edit** - I probably did not understand the requirement correctly. Check out these demos.

http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~DeckPanel
http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~StackPanel

T Broyers Suggestion - http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~DisclosurePanel

Comment: DeckLayoutPanel seams like what im looking for...Im learning gwt..Can you give an example of how to do this..

Comment: Updated answer with tutorial from slideshare. Note: ensure you are aware of DeckPanel and DeckLayoutPanel.

Comment: this example says the widgets are put on top of each other..so each of my box will be a widget and i layer it on the decklayout? so what happen when i say show widget1?? does it look like a expand/collapse?? or are the other widgets hidden??

Comment: I updated answer with demos for DeckPanel, StackPanel and Disclosure panels. Note as T Broyer mentioned you may need to customize them as per your need.

Comment: i had a look at the demos..what i need is similar to the stackpanel except i dont what the sliding option..just open close..Is it possible to customize stackpanel to behave in such a way?